# How to download multiple files with android DownloadManager so that it appears as one notification

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, android-download-manager

I'm using DownloadManager to download files.

But I have multiple files that "belong" together as one item, so I'd like to have a "queue" for those, and display the notification in a way that it shows the progress of the "queue" (let's say I added 5 files to the queue, so it would show 20% after the 1st file is downloaded, 40% after 2 of them,...  or get the total filesize as max value for the progress file, and increase the progress bar according the already downloaded files sizes)

currently, I already downloading the files with, but the downloadmanager show me the progress for each file separately instead of 1 entry showing the progress for the whole queue together.

[Mutiple files as multiple downloads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wluCf.png), it should be one notification with the total progress.

How can I show a notification with the total download progress instead of seperate downloads?

This question is related to: [How to download multiple files with android DownloadManager so that it appears in one queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053740/how-to-download-multiple-files-with-android-downloadmanager-so-that-it-appears-i)